# Is it possible to create nested sections in the R outline that function as such in the document?

Tags: r, rstudio, code-organization, outline

I'm using RScript files, haven't yet made the leap to RMarkdown.
I am trying to stay organized with my notes and code, and use the outline heavily.

[As such, my code looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUcdp.png) Essentially:

```
#Main Subject Heading 1
##Sub Heading 1 which is meant to be nested under Main Subject Heading 1----
# Info for sub heading 1
# Info for sub heading 1
# Info for sub heading 1
##Sub Heading 2 which is meant to be nested under Main Subject Heading 1----
# Info for sub heading 2
# Info for sub heading 2

#Main Subject Heading 2----
##Sub Heading 1 which is meant to be nested under Main Subject Heading 2----
```

This *visually* looks correct in the outline; the sub headings are indented under the main headings. However, if I try to collapse the main subject heading, it only collapses info under that MSH up until sub heading 1, and I have to collapse each sub-heading separately.

Is there a way in R Script files to make it so that collapsing the Main Subject Heading will also collapse all nested sections? In searching for nesting-related codes I'm just finding functions relating to actually nesting data frames and the like.

Comment: FYI `rscript` is a command line tool for running R scripts without a GUI - like if you wanted your computer to automatically run R code every day at noon. My guess is your question is about editing code in RStudio - is that correct?